# Utilize more threads in viewport

Tags: 3d-view, performance

I've got a threadripper 3960X, which is great for rendering. However, when I have a large scene and am moving around in the viewport (no animations or anything, just a ridiculous amount of verts) it looks like only one thread is being used. This is making it impossible to do anything. Even just deleting an object takes almost a full minute and "blender is not responding". Is there any settings to increase thread usage in the viewport?

Comment: "a ridiculous amount of verts" will for sure slow down any computer. Learn how to optimize your objects so that you don't need that many. On top of that,  use subsurf , multires, decimate, and other modifiers, to bring the number of vertices displayed in the viewport to a manageable number. Switch off the objects you are not working on.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future projects, this one though I got a scene from Turbo Squid so I don't have much control over the meshes. I'll go through and turn stuff off though. Thanks!

Comment: You have all the control on the meshes you want. Use decimate and multires.